# JQGrid MultiSelect check boxes not unchecking when clicking on rows

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

i have the following JQGrid

```
   $("#proposalsTable").jqGrid({
    url: url,
    datatype: 'json',
    mtype: 'GET',
    altRows: false,
    colNames: ['Model', 'Model Year', 'Cabinet', 'Shell', 'Customer', 'Designed By', 'Date'],
    colModel: [

            { name: 'Model', index: 'Model', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'ModelYear', index: 'ModelYear', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'CabinetColor', index: 'CabinetColor', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'ShellColor', index: 'ShellColor', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'CustomerName', index: 'CustomerName', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'DesignedBy', index: 'DesignedBy', align: 'left' },
            { name: 'ProposalDate', index: 'ProposalDate', align: 'left' },

            ],
    pager: jQuery("#proposalsPager"),
    rowNum: 50,
    rowList: [50, 75, 100],
    sortname: 'ProposalDate',
    sortorder: "desc",
    viewrecords: true,
    height: '700px',
    multiselect: true,
    autowidth: true,
    shrinkToFit: true

});
```

When I go through and check the check boxes the check box is checked and the row color shows that it is selected... But if I go back through and just click on the row(not on the check box) The row color shows it is not selected but the check box stays checked.
If I run code to see if there really are checked at this point. They are not. But it I go back through and check the check boxes the rows get de-selected and although the checkbox shows a check..But the grid thinks that the rows are not selected if I run code to look at it. Very Very Very strange.
How can I either make clicking the rows do nothing, or make sure that they do in fact uncheck the check boxes.
I hope that makes sense.
Thanks!

Comment: I found the issue and just wanted to put it up here for everyone else.

I forced it to use jquery 1.4.4

       <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Instead of getting the latest version 


This fixed the issue I was having above..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the issue and just wanted to put it up here for everyone else.

I forced it to use jquery 1.4.4

```
   <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Instead of getting the latest version

This fixed the issue I was having above.

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be to implement a function in your options to override the `onSelectRow` event. This takes a rowId and a status argument.

From there, you can manipulate the row based on the rowId.

See [http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:events](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aevents) for more about the events available, and how to override them. NOTE: if you override and return false, the default event handler doesn't fire.